# Git - Can you do something with rebase that you can't do with merge?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Every time I've tried a `rebase`, I've been involved in an infinite loop of unsolvable conflicts. Before resolving x conflict, y conflict appeared, and then x conflict again, and so on.

The point is that (apparently) `merge`, or even `cherry-pick`, provide the same functionality you could expect from `rebase`, don't they? If not, which is the usefulness of `rebase`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rebase` rewrites history. It does ***way*** more than `merge` or `cherry-pick` -- a very advanced tool that takes practice (and can be dangerous, since it rewrites history...be careful with `git push -f`). When `rebase` is used similarly to `merge`, the process is quite distinctively different.

`git fetch origin && git merge origin/master`:

- download changes from origin
- merge changes on top of local branch
- resolve conflicts and commit

`git fetch origin && git rebase origin/master`:

- download changes from origin
- reset local branch to a common point in history (a commit that both local/remote repos share)
- fast forward to origin
- apply your commits on top of new commits one by one
- resolve conflicts and commit for each local change

The big advantage of `rebase` in this situation is that you're just updating your local repo and applying your commits on top and there won't be any "gross" merge commit saying "hey, I just merged this stuff in." The downside is that if you have a ton of commits that modify the same files, you will have to resolve the conflict over and over again since there is no "gross" merge commit.

But again, `rebase` is a really advanced tool meant for rewriting history. You can amend previous commit titles, delete commits in the past, squash many commits together, etc. [Read up on it!](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: So, rewriting history so "freely", makes you lose traceability, doesn't it?

Comment: That's a decent way to sum it up, @Julen.

Answer (score 2):

I use `rebase` in only one case. The case:

1. I have `master` branch with current version of an app.
2. I create `feature-branch` for a new feature
3. I make a few commits in `feature-branch`
4. **I make a few hot commits in the master branch**
5. Now I want to have that commits in the `feature-branch` and I do `rebase` in this case.
6. I done with the `feature-branch` and I just merge it into master.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git checkout feature-branch
   git commit -am "feature commit #1"
   git commit -am "feature commit #2"
   git commit -am "feature commit #3"
   git checkout master
   git commit -am "hot fix"
   git checkout feature-branch
   git rebase master
   git commit -am "i'm done"
   git checkout master
   git merge feature-branch
   ```

This allows me to be on the top of `master` branch and have a clean git history.